# Design v24.2.1 Issue with title in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am frustrated that **toolbar title keeps disappearing after the image from network gets loaded into the image view**. I tried following all the suggestions on stackoverflow online, none of them worked...

**This issue didn't persist when I was using design v23.0.4.**

I am loading an image into the ImageView with id : networkImageView using Glide Library.

Here's my XML snippet after removing all the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attributes. **Problem persists even after removing this attribute...**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".movies.moviedetails.MovieDetailsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/networkImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/backdrop_def_image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Please help me with this issue. Why the hell does Google keep reintroducing bugs into latest design libraries? They fix bugs in one version and add the same bugs in another version.

Comment: try to change version from `24.2.1` to this `24.1.1`.

Comment: Is that the solution for everything? Downgrading design library every single time... I'll try nevertheless.

Comment: @Ironman, Surprisingly 24.1.1 works and the bug disappears. But I'm not too happy with the solution. Thanks for your inputs...

Comment: I know that but The version have bug and you can not fix it. So I give you workaround that will reduce your time to work with your Project. otherwise it will not fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `support Library version` from `24.2.1` to `24.1.1` to show title in CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Because in the Latest version `24.2.1` it was bug and can not fix yet. So for the workaround you have to descrease the version of the supprort library as I suggested.